# Binary is rejected on iTunesconnect, how could i find the issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, ipa

I have submitted the binary for review on iTunesconnect it is rejected with message we found 2 or more issues while using app on iPhone or iPad on iOS 9.3.4 or more ?How could i ask apple team to what is the issue ?

Comment: message will have description along with section number under which it is rejected. Please share the section number so that we can guide you further

Comment: @Amod Gokhale message is Performance 2.1 we discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 on wi-fi connected to an..

Comment: There are no steps provided by apple further? Usually they provide exact steps that caused application to reject.If steps are not provided or you are able to test app in above devices you should file an appeal to review board.

Comment: Here is detail description from Apple review guildeline for 2.1 2.1 App Completeness. Link for apple guildines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#performance